# (python) sgmlparser and how to extract data between tags, not attributes/values

Tags: python, html

Every example I see for sgmlparser involves finding a tag, then finding the attributes/values of the tag. So for  it would be the ability to extract 'google.com' out. but i want the data between tags. so if i used sgmlparser, i would look for  and extract out everything in that div until it's closing  tag. is that the job of sgmlparser, or am i using the wrong library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you mention div's, I gather you want to parse HTML. For doing that your best choice is [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).